# Can I make IE8 and below display a completely different website?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I am creating a website for my company's product (I am pretty new at this), and I have just realised that A LOT of the formatting I have done seems to be completely ignored by IE versions 8 and below.

Is there a way for me to make the website direct the users of these browsers to a completely different and extremely simplified version of my website?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to fix the issues by using a different stylesheet for IE8 and below.
This can be done using the conditional statements.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  // Your IE8 and below HTML code here or
  // Perhaps importing a specific style sheet as
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8_and_below.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

If you wish to have a simplified version for IE8 and below, add this script on the page for which you want to have a minimized version.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     window.location = "http://www.example.com/ie8";
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Then add your HTML markup on ie8 HTML page which will be only for IE8 and below.

Comment: And of course I only just saw this...thankfully I need this now for a new website too, so thank you so much! I will definitely give that a go :)

Answer (score 0):

You can target IE versions using conditional statements to include CSS files only to be loaded by those browsers.  For example, to load a stylesheet only in IE8 and below, use:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You can read more about conditional statements for IE [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

Alternatively you could sniff out the browser user-agent, and redirect accordingly but this is a less ideal solution, and it would involve page duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the version of the browser by the DOM object. Then you can put that in a if-else and check the version to be greater or not and then according redirect your page to somewhere else. You can also check if the user is using IE or some other browser.

```
    var ver=navigator.appVersion;
    var brw=navigator.userAgent;
if(brw.equals("msie"))
{
    if(ver<8)
    //redirect
    else
    //stay or something else
}
```

hope this helps.